# raw_input without leaving a history in readline

Tags: python, history, readline, tab-completion

Is there a way of using raw_input without leaving a sign in the readline history, so that it don't show when tab-completing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could make a function something like

```
import readline

def raw_input_no_history():
    input = raw_input()
    readline.remove_history_item(readline.get_current_history_length()-1)
    return input
```

and call that function instead of raw_input. You may not need the minus 1 dependent on where you call it from.

Comment: Thanks. But you forgot to return the output of raw_input ;)

Comment: Just note that if the history file is empty and the user doesn't type anything and just hits enter the code would fail. It's better to only call `readline.remove_history_item` if there was any `input` from the user