# Remove items from iPython's history

Tags: python, readline, ipython

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [raw_input without leaving a history in readline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202127/raw-input-without-leaving-a-history-in-readline)

I'm working on a simple interactive application that relies on iPython.  I'm running into a problem where prompting a user for input (e.g. with raw_input()) adds the item to iPython's history, which I'd rather it didn't.

A session might look like this:

```
In [1]: foo = MyClass()

In [2]: foo.do_something()
>>> Enter something:  bar
Out [2]: results of foo.do_something()
```

At this point, the last item in the shell's history is 'bar', which isn't particularly useful.  Is there a simple way to prevent user input for raw_input() from getting into the history?

Edit:  My bad, this is a problem with readline, not iPython, and there's a more direct question about it (with an answer) here:
[raw_input without leaving a history in readline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202127/raw-input-without-leaving-a-history-in-readline)

Comment: It is actually possible to fix this in IPython as well, and we might aim to do so for the next release.