# How to stop user input from appearing in history in cmd module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-cmd

Consider this minimal program that uses the [`cmd`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/cmd.html) module:

```
import cmd

class Shell(cmd.Cmd):
    def do_input(self, _arg):
        '''Ask the user to input a string.'''
        s = input('String: ')
        print(s)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Shell().cmdloop()
```

Here's a sample interaction with this program:

```
(Cmd) input
String: Hello!
Hello!
(Cmd)
```

Now the problem is that upon pressing the up keyboard button, the last history item is from the user input (i.e. `Hello!`) rather than from the shell's prompt (i.e. `input`).

The question is: How can I get only the history of commands entered at the shell prompt (without the history of inputs entered using `input()`)?

Comment: The history feature doesn't have anything to do with the `cmd` module; it's coming from the `readline` library that Python uses for `input()` when possible.  You can manipulate its history list, to get rid of the unwanted item perhaps: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202127/raw-input-without-leaving-a-history-in-readline for an example.